# DDD Child object references

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have an invoice object, which consists of items, and each item has a relation to service.

Following structure.

```
{
   "invoiceId" : "dsr23343",
   "items":{
      "id":1,
      "service":{
         "serviceCode":"HTT"
      }
   }
}
```

One of my requirements is that the item should not have a relation to service which does not exist in our system.
From my understanding, domain objects should never enter in an invalid state. 
So what I am doing is following:

```
var service = new Service("SomeService");
var item = new Item(service);
invoice.AddItem(item);
```

My question is, should i require `AddItem` function to receive Repository as second parameter, and throw exception if Service does not exist in database?

Comment: Have you considered using a ServiceFactory and validating the service there?

Comment: Is Service an aggregate root?

Comment: You need not wait until the item is added to the invoice. Creating the service object itself should fail if that service is not valid(does not exist in the system)

Comment: @arulKumaran what if the service object is valid for creating, f.e. if you wish to add a new service to the DB, but it is invalid to be added in the item in that state, or if you need to add 500 items. should i have one DB call to validate all 500, or 500 db calls to validate one by one ?

Comment: @Robert, it is very difficult to answer your question without much idea on how your objects are related. What is the relation between 'service' and 'item'? Is it one-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-many etc..? But the essence is that you should validate before relating the objects. In this case, it is the statement 'new Item(service)'. If that service is not supposed to be linked with that item, that statement shouldn't pass. where to put that validation logic depends on the relation between 'service' and 'item'

Comment: @ArulKumaran I see, so it is not unusual to inject repository in domain object functions or factories, to make sure that object is not in invalid state?

Comment: @Robert, AFAIK, It is not advisable to use repositories in domain objects. That way you keep the domain free of infrastructure(like DB) and also keep it testable. You can use a factory/builder to create your item and have a validation service(which has the repo) in that factory/builder which does the validation for you before creating the object. Using repositories in factories is fine.

Comment: @ArulKumaran i see. and if i have method to change one of that properties, i can have that same method to receive ValidationService interface as well? FE invoice.AddItems(items, IValidationService) ?

Comment: I would not do it as it leads to coupling

Comment: @ArulKumaran could you please tell me what would be your suggestion for this scenario? How would a domain validate if the added items are valid for that particular invoice, if the validation requires data from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, should i require AddItem function to receive Repository as second parameter, and throw exception if Service does not exist in database?

Short answer: sure, why not?

Longer answer...

If Service and Invoice are part of the same aggregate, then the repository is unnecessary -- just look at the state of the aggregate.  So what follows assumes that there is a transaction boundary between the Invoice and the Service.

Using a Repository as the argument is a bit too much stuff -- Invoice doesn't need to load the Service, it just needs to know if the Service *exists*.  So instead of putting a Repository in the method signature, you could use a DomainService that supports the "does this service exist?" query.

(The implementation of the DomainService probably does a lookup in the Repository -- we're not doing magic here, we're just isolating Invoice from implementation details it doesn't need to know about).

Using the more restrictive interface in the signature documents clearly what the integration contract is between these components.

**That said**, the *requirement* is very suspicious.  If Service and Invoice are in different aggregates, then they potentially have different life cycles.  What is supposed to happen when you try to load an invoice, that includes an item that references a service which no longer exists?  Is that use case supposed to explode? if so, it's going to be hard to edit the invoice to fix the problem....

What if, while you are adding the item to the invoice, some other thread is deleting the service...?

Review Udi Dahan's essay: [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).  Executive summary - if your model is sensitive to microsecond variations in timing, you probably aren't modelling your business.

You've got at least three other alternatives to protect this "invariant".

One is at the client level; if you don't let the client produce invalid service codes, then you aren't going to have this problem.  Input validation belongs in the client component or in the application component, not so much the model.  That is, it's the sort of thing that you might check when the application is constructing the ServiceCode from the DTO that traveled across the process boundary.

One is downstream of the model - if you can detect invoice items that reference service codes that are invalid, then you can broadcast an exception report, and use the contingency response process to manage the problem.  Consistency issues that are rare, cheap to detect, easy to fix don't need tight validation in the domain model.

One is within the model itself - if creation of an invoice item is tightly coupled to the lifetime of a service, then maybe the item is created by the service, rather than by the invoice.  For example

```
class Service {
    reportUsage(Customer, TimePeriod)
}
```

Wouldn't be an unusual looking signature, and you can probably be confident that the Service raising a domain event is going to correctly report its own ServiceCode.

Comment: I like your solution about validation at the client level, but then the domain object would be allowed to enter to an invalid state. I guess i should make a compromise depending on the business requirements.

Comment: @Robert you need to raise a business question - what happens if we add an item for the service that does not exist. Usually, if you do such operation, you got this "SomeService" string from somewhere, so probably it existed at the moment your command was formed. This makes the aforementioned question completely valid and it is not "invalid state", it is just state that you have to deal with. Also calculate what is the probability for this to occur, referring to the DDDx Greg Young's talk about over-engineering.